# How to get all alpha values of scikit-learn SVM classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I need the alpha values, which are the Lagrange multipliers of the SVM dual problem, after training a SVM classifier with scikit-learn. According to the document, it seems that scikit-learn provides only `svm.dual_coef_`, which is the product of the Lagrange multiplier alpha and the label of a data point.

I tried to calculate the alpha value manually by dividing the elements of `svm.dual_coef_` by the data label, but since `svm.dual_coef_` stores only the coefficients of the support vectors, I'm not sure if I iterate over this array, the order of support vectors would be the same as the order in the original training data.

So is there a reliable way to get the alpha values of support vectors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As alpha values are by definition positive you can get it through taking abs of dual_coefs:

```
alphas = np.abs(svm.dual_coef_)
```

whis is a direct consequence of the fact that

```
svm.dual_coef_[i] = labels[i] * alphas[i]
```

where `labels[i]` is either `-1` or `+1` and `alphas[i]` are always positive. Futhermore, you can also get each label through

```
labels = np.sign(svm.dual_coef_)
```

using the same observation. This is also why scikit-learn does not store alphas as such - they are uniquely represented by dual_coefs_, together with labels.

It is easy to understand it once you analyze all possible cases:

- `labels[i] == -1` and `alphas[i] > 0` => `dual_coef_[i] < 0` and `dual_coef_[i] == -alphas[i] == labels[i] * alphas[i]`
- `labels[i] == -1` and `alphas[i] < 0` => **impossible (alphas are non-negative)**
- `labels[i] == -1` and `alphas[i]== 0` => **it is not a support vector**
- `labels[i] == +1` and `alphas[i] > 0` => `dual_coef_[i] > 0` and `dual_coef_[i] == alphas[i] == labels[i] * alphas[i]`
- `labels[i] == +1` and `alphas[i] < 0` => **impossible (alphas are non-negative)**
- `labels[i] == +1` and `alphas[i]== 0` => **it is not a support vector**

Consequently, if `dual_coef_[i]` is positive then it is the `alphas[i]` coefficient, and it belongs to positive class, and if it is negative, `alphas[i] == -dual_coef_[i]` and it belongs to negative class.

Comment: Can I do the same thing with multiclass SVM?

Comment: SVM is inherently binary. Multiclass SVM is nothing but many binary SVMs so you can read out each one.